# A question on the requirement of a quadrilateral being an adventitious quadrangle

Tags: geometry

There is a special type of problem called Langley’s Adventitious Angles. See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%E2%80%99s_Adventitious_Angles

The problem was solved and has the following generalization:-

“A quadrilateral such as BCEF (with a, b, c, d as the 4 interior angles) in which **the angles formed by all triples of vertices are rational multiples of π** is called an adventitious quadrangle.”

I don’t quite understand the meaning of words in bold. An illustrative example would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that if $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are any three of $B,C,E,F$ then $\angle XYZ$ has measure (in radians)  of the shape $r\pi$ for some rational number $r$. Equivalently, since $\pi$ radians is $180^\circ$, it means that every angle is a rational number of degrees. Thus angles like $\frac{99}{7}$ degrees or $17$ degrees are OK, but (for example) an angle of $20\sqrt{2}$ degrees is not.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the image:
[image: Example of adventitious quadrilateral]

Taken from Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks for the info. Don't quite understand (1) does the figure imply a, b, c, d are examples of the angles in question? (2) does the figure imply a = b and c = d?

Comment: It implies that e is the angles in question, and also a does not have to equal b and c does not have to equal d. This is just an example, so for example, if a=28 degrees, b=25 degrees, c=38 degrees, and d is 48 degrees, see if you can solve this problem.